# Is it possible to intercept any service other than constant using $decorator?

Tags: angularjs

I tried using one of the service method, value(). it is working for me

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

    app.value('val','Hi');

    app.config(function ($provide) {
        $provide.decorator('val', function ($delegate) {
            return $delegate + ' Angular!';
        });
    });
```

I want to know more about $provide.decorator and how it is intercepting the other service methods like factory, service and provider.

Comment: And what's wrong with reading the documentation/tutorials about `$provide.decorator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`decorator` allows you to intercept the creation of services within the angular workflow. There are several use-cases in which you should consider using it:

1. Adding functionality to third party services
2. Choosing a specific service implementation
3. Wrapping services for caching or debugging purposes

Let's say you have an 'alertService' like this:

```
class AlertService {

    public alert(message: string) : void {
        return alert(message);
    }

module.service("alertService", AlertService);
```

Let's assume that this is an external service (3rd party for instance) and you want to add a 'confirm' method that allows user to cancel or proceed an operation. In this case you can extend the service with `decorator`, like this:

```
module.config(function($provide){

    $provide.decorator('alertService', function($delegate) {

        $delegate.confirm = function(message) {
       // method logic...
    };

    return $delegate;

    });

});
```

Look at angular's documentation for further study: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators